# HTML: multiple drop down choosen plugin version mismatch issue

Tags: jquery, version, jquery-chosen

There are a lot of jQuery libraries and plugins in my project. The version of jQuery is 3.4.1.

I want to add a multi-select drop down. When I search in Stack Overflow I got a solution using the Chosen plugin. The version of jQuery of this plugin is 2.1.1. When I add this plugin and code of drop down in my project it is not working properly. I think it is due to version mismatch. There is any solution for this?

Comment: Simplest solution: pick an up-to-date plugin.  I suggest considering [tag:select2]

Comment: You should also review at least the summary page for your "chosen" (see what I did there) plugin.  https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/ **Deprecated** *This version of Chosen is not currently under active development while we decide on its future direction.*

Comment: I already tested the latest version of chosen.

Comment: Then you have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - How do I do X (multi-select drop down), pick a solution Y (use chosen) then ask a question about Y instead of asking about X (though asking for a plugin would be off-topic).